# How to name html files produced by nops_eval with the students ID?

Tags: r, r-exams

I am aware that `nops_eval` creates folders named with students' ID, and inside each of those folders, an HTML file (with the same name for all students) is created. I would like to have the HTML files with the students' ID or the students' names. It would be necessary to have a folder per student, just the HTML files all in the same folder, without Is it possible?
The code used:

```
eval <- nops_eval(register = "register_df.csv",
          solutions = "solutions.rds",
          scans = "nops_scan.zip",
          language = "pt",
          eval = exams_eval(partial = F, negative = -0.25, rule = "false"),
          dir = "eval",
          interactive = T,
          mark = F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, in version 2.4-0 `nops_eval()` gained the option to plug in custom writers for the evaluation results. So, in principle, this could be used. However, if the focus is just to rename the HTML files, I would probably simply `unzip()` the ZIP file, `file.rename()` the HTML files, and then `file.remove()` the previous directories.

For me on Linux this works:

```
f <- unzip("nops_eval.zip")
id <- strsplit(f, "/", fixed = TRUE)
id <- sapply(id, function(x) x[length(x) - 1])
for(i in seq_along(id)) {
  file.rename(f[i], paste0(id[i], ".html"))
  file.remove(id[i])
}
```

*Note:* Possibly, the file paths in `f` are separated with a backslash rather than a slash on Windows. If so, you would have to replace `"/"` with `"\\"` in the `strsplit()` call.